# flutter/dart for loop doesn't work properly

Tags: flutter, list, dart, for-loop

Hello today i had some weird issues working with dart/flutter. Im trying to check if a word is contained in a List of Strings but dart always only checks the last element of the list.
The list of words in the txt file goes something like this:

```
...
wall
...
zoo
```

This is my working function (only works for zoo since its the last element):

```
  getBIPWords() async {
    bipwords = await rootBundle.loadString('assets/textfiles/bip_words.txt');
    splittedbipwords = bipwords.split(new RegExp(r"\n"));
   
    for (String word in splittedbipwords) {
      if(word != "zoo"){
        print(word.toString());
        print("no zoo");
      }
      else if(word == "zoo"){
        print(word.toString());
        print("zoo found");
      }
      else{
        print("bug");
      }
    }
  }
```

I get this console output as expected:

```
...
I/flutter (  641): zero
I/flutter (  641): no zoo
I/flutter (  641): zone
I/flutter (  641): no zoo
I/flutter (  641): zoo
I/flutter (  641): zoo found
```

But as soon as I choose another word than "zoo" eventough its in the list everything wont work properly.

```
  getBIPWords() async {
    bipwords = await rootBundle.loadString('assets/textfiles/bip_words.txt');
    splittedbipwords = bipwords.split(new RegExp(r"\n"));
    
    for (String word in splittedbipwords) {
      if(word != "wall"){
        print(word.toString());
        print("no wall");
      }
      else if(word == "wall"){
        print(word.toString());
        print("wall found");
      }
      else{
        print("bug");
      }
    }
  }
```

Console Output:

```
...
I/flutter ( 1020): walk
I/flutter ( 1020): no wall
I/flutter ( 1020): wall
I/flutter ( 1020): no wall
I/flutter ( 1020): walnut
I/flutter ( 1020): no wall
...
```

Im so confused since it literally does print wall. Whats going on here? Can anyone help?

Comment: I bet there's some non-\n whitespace in that string.

Comment: Nope checked for that one first of all. There are no spaces or anything else that causes the issue. However I tested multiple files now and it seems to be an issue for all of flutter/dart langue. You cant properly sperate by new RegExp(r"\n"). I fixed it by changing my .txt file from newlines to simple spaces between the words ans seperating by that... Weird issue...

Comment: You said ".txt".  Are you on windows, where lines are separated by \r\n?  That would be your issue there.  You should use \s+ as the separator.

Comment: You should use `LineSplitter` if you want to split lines in a cross-platform way.

Answer (score 0):

I tested multiple files now and it seems to be an issue for all of flutter/dart langue. You cant properly sperate by new RegExp(r"\n"). I fixed it by changing my .txt file from newlines to simple spaces between the words ans seperating by that... Weird issue...